# PL/SQL stored procedure compilation error

Tags: plsql

I tried creating a stored procedure but While executing the below stored procedure, i am getting compilation error:

```
create or replace procedure "Employee"    
is    
begin 
select unique ID from prod p where p.value in('R44',
'R76',
'R79',
'R20',
'R02',
'RY1',
'R71',
'R38',
'R58',
'RM8',
'RW8',
'R74',
'R73',
'R99',
'R72',
'R19',
'R33',
'RN3',
'R34',
'RP8',
'R22',
'R75',
'R01',
'R67',
'R27',
'R28',
'R57',
'RC5',
'RW7',
'RZ9',
'R77',
'R07',
'RW6')  

end;    
/
```

Comment: this is not working. Can please anyone help me out?

Comment: There are a few problems with this. Firstly, you're missing a semi-colon at the end of the select statement. Secondly (and most importantly) you cannot perform a select without an into clause in PL/SQL. I'd probably recommend you read the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm

Comment: What do you want to do with the result of the query?
Read carefully the comments of Chrisrs2292; these make sense. But a select into wont work here, unless you are for 100% sure that the result is just 1 row.

Comment: Also don't name the procedure `"Employee"` (in double quotes) unless you want to be forced to refer to it with the exact same captialisation and double quotes forever. Just call it `employee` (unquoted) to keep things simple. (Though `employee` is kind of an odd name for a procedure. What does it do?)

Comment: btw when posting code that gives compilation errors, please include the error details. In this case it would have indicated the line after `'RW6')` with the message `PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` (which itself should have told you what you needed to know).

Comment: I am using the below procedure but as my select query is giving me multiple rows, i cannot use into keyword in select query. How can i handle this situation,

Comment: reate or replace procedure "Employee"    
is    
begin 
select unique ID into temp from prod p where p.value in('R44',
'R76',
'R79',
'R20',
'R02',
'RY1',
'R71',
'R38',
'R58',
'RM8',
'RW8',
'R74',
'R73',
'R99',
'R72',
'R19',
'R33',
'RN3',
'R34',
'RP8',
'R22',
'R75',
'R01',
'R67',
'R27',
'R28',
'R57',
'RC5',
'RW7',
'RZ9',
'R77',
'R07',
'RW6') ; 

end;    
/

Answer (score 0):

These is a lot wrong with your code. 
In your example you are also missing an `;` behind your sequence. 
If you wish to show the output of that sequence on your screen you cannot do it that way. 
Here is an working example that might give you an indication:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cProd IS
            select unique(ID) Id from prod p where p.value in('R44','R76',
            'R79','R20','R02','RY1','R71','R38','R58','RM8','RW8','R74','R73','R99','R72','R19','R33','RN3',
            'R34','RP8','R22','R75','R01','R67','R27','R28','R57','RC5','RW7','RZ9','R77','R07','RW6');
    rProd cProd%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN cProd;
    FETCH cProd INTO rProd;
    CLOSE cProd;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rProd.Id);
END;  
/
```

[Link about fetching from a cursor.](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/cursors/fetch.php)

Edit: 
In `rProd` the above example stored all output lines from your query.